# zend framework regex problem: "Internal error while using the pattern"

Tags: php, regex, forms, zend-framework

I've tested my regular expression on multiple testers and I've tried multiple regular expressions too but I keep getting the error: "Internal error while using the pattern  '/^(04\d{2}/(\d{2} )\d{2} \d{2})$/'". I know it's probably not the best regex but I couldn't find a good one and I'm not really a pro at this and I have to move on.
The phone numbers it should be matching are 04dd/dd dd dd with d being a number between 0 and 9.
This is the code I'm using when creating the form.

```
$phone = $this->addElement('text', 'phone', array(
        'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
        'validators' => array(
            array('regex', false, array('/^(04\d{2}/(\d{2} )\d{2} \d{2})$/'))
        ),
        'required'   => true,
        'label'      => 'Phone:',
    ));
```

How can I solve this problem?
Thanks already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to escape the slash:

```
array('regex', false, array('/^(04\d{2}\/(\d{2} )\d{2} \d{2})$/'))
```

Comment: Hmm, I thought I already tried that but there probably were more errors in the regex at that time. It did the trick, thanks!